# Dialogflow CX Messenger renderCustomText() and renderCustomCard() functions not rendering text correctly

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I am using Dialogflow CX Messenger integration for one of my bots. I'm trying to use [these](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#rendercustomtext) [functions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#rendercustomcard). They work well until I use certain special characters such as accented characters. This happens commonly as one of the languages of my bot is spanish.

For example:  `"This is displayed correctly, until I use spanish characters such as ¿ Á é ñ . Emoji break it too: "`

ends up being displayed as `This is displayed correctly, until I use spanish characters such as Â¿ Ã Ã© Ã± . Emoji break it too: ðŸ¤”`

[Example of what the output looks like in the messenger itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7PP6.png)

This doesn't happen when the message itself comes from Dialogflow, it works fine when a response comes from there. Even emojis work. The issue only appears when I try to use these functions.

My code uses the [embed code](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#embed) provided by the Dialogflow CX console, and I added a script that looks like this

```
window.addEventListener('dfMessengerLoaded', function (event) {
    const exampleText = "This is displayed correctly, until I use spanish characters such as ¿ Á é ñ . Emoji break it too: ";
    dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger');
    dfMessenger.renderCustomText(exampleText);
});
```

I have tried using the renderCustomCard() function and ran into the same issue.

Any help is very appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out, the problem wasn't with the function themselves.

It's just that I was lacking an UTF-8 reference: `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` in my HTML. Once this was added in everything worked correctly.

What I found weird is how text sent from Dialogflow itself renders correctly without the need for this tag, which is why I misdiagnosed the problem.